# How to get string after character oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have `VP3 - Art & Design and HS5 - Health & Social Care`, I need to get string after `'-'` in Oracle. Can this be achieved using substring?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For a string operation as simple as this, I might just use the base `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()` functions.  In the query below, we take the substring of your column beginning at two positions *after* the hyphen.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '-') + 2) AS subject
FROM yourTable
```

We could also use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` here (see Gordon's answer), but it would be a bit more complex and the performance might not be as good as the above query.

Comment: Thnaks a lot Tim

Answer (score 15):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^-]+', 1, 2)
```

If you want to remove an optional space, then you can use `trim()`:

```
select trim(leading ' ', regexp_substr(col, '[^-]+', 1, 2))
```

The non-ovious parameters mean

- `1` -- search from the first character of the source. `1` is the default, but you have to set it anyway to be able to provide the second parameter.
- `2` -- take the second match as the result substring. the default would be 1.

Comment: This is a good solution if col is a complex expression, so you don't have to mention that twice.

Comment: I was getting a syntax error when I tried `trim(leading ' ', regexp_substr(col, '[^-]+', 1, 2))`. I used this instead: `trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^-]+', 1, 2))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN INSTR(value, '-') > 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '-') + 1)
       END AS subject
FROM   table_name
```

or

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '-(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS subject
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'VP3 - Art & Design and HS5 - Health & Social Care' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1-2-3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> ```
> | SUBJECT                                      |
> | :------------------------------------------- |
> |  Art & Design and HS5 - Health & Social Care |
> | 2-3                                          |
> | null                                         |
> ```

## Trimming leading white-space:

If you want to trim the leading white-space then you can use:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN INSTR(value, '-') > 0
       THEN LTRIM(SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '-') + 1))
       END AS subject
FROM   table_name
```

or

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '-\s*(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS subject
FROM   table_name
```

Which both output:

> ```
> | SUBJECT                                     |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | Art & Design and HS5 - Health & Social Care |
> | 2-3                                         |
> | null                                        |
> ```

---

## Why the naive solutions don't always work:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '-') + 2) AS subject
FROM   table_name
```

Does not work in 2 cases:

- It finds the index of the `-` character and then skips 2 characters (the `-` character and then the assumed white-space character); if the second character is not a white-space character then it will miss the first character of the substring (i.e. if the input is `1-2-3` then the output would be `-3` rather than `2-3`).
- It assumes that there will always be a `-` character in the string; if this is not the case then it will erroneously return the substring starting from the second character rather than returning `NULL` (i.e. if the input is `123456` then the output is `23456` rather than `NULL`).

---

Using the regular expression:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '[^-]+', 1, 2)
FROM   table_name
```

Does not find the substring after the 1st `-` character; it will find the substring between the 1st and 2nd `-` characters and strip any characters outside that range (inclusive of the `-` characters). So if the input is `VP3 - Art & Design and HS5 - Health & Social Care` then the output is `Art & Design and HS5` rather than the expected  `Art & Design and HS5 - Health & Social Care`.